# Laravel routes don't seem to go to correct place

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, routes

I am linking with localhost/offers/create however it doesn't seem to find the right template,  instead I get sent to single.blade.php when I should get edit.blade.php

http://codepad.org/vpYj1bub is a link to my code.

```
Route::get('offers/{id}', function($id) {
$offer = Offer::find($id);
return View::make('offers.single')
->with('offer', $offer);
});
```

The above route seems to be the one that is getting hit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My problem revolved around missing

```
Route::pattern('id', '[0-9]+');
```

Which kept my create from showing up under id

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: @Pop how can this be not providing the answer if OP himself is answering it :)

Comment: This does provide a solution to the question. The point @LIUFA was pointing out is that {id} has not been provided with a pattern. If the pattern for id was provided then the route could potentially work. But if you dont want to provide a pattern reorder your routes! Work backwards, with routes, more exact routes at the top less precise routes at the bottom i.e. offers/{id} should come after offers/create